# How to list the @Cities entity values my Bot works with in Watson Conversation Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have an Entity
    @City = Austin, Providence, London and Boston
[image]
I simply want to answer the question what cities does this bot work with? 
[image]

And then respond with:

```
Here are the cities this works with $Locations ,  Which city do you want?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dialog, [you have access to all the entities that were detected (recognized) in the user input](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#access-entity). However, you do not have access to all the defined entities and their possible values.

What you could do is to define a context variable with the allowed values. That variable could even be dynamically populated (see this [tutorial for database access from within Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot)). Another option is to hardcode the response. But this only works well with few values and infrequent changes.